# Page not loading after res.render()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am developing a web app with an Express sever, and I can't find the reason for the page not to load after I call res.render().

My folder structure is as follows (omitting the files and folders that are unnecessary for this question):

```
- app
   - views
      - partials
   adminDashboard.ejs
   welcome.ejs
- lib
   - controllers
      auth.controller.js
   - models
      user.model.js
   - routes
      routes.js
- public
   - js
      login.js
server.js
```

The code in question is as follows:

**login.js**

```js
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const username = document.getElementById("inputUsername").value
    const password = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value

    const user = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }

    return fetch(`/login`, {
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(response => window.location.reload)
})
```

**auth.controller.js**

```js
async function login(request, response) {
    try {
        //We must validate what is sent by the frond end
        if (!(request.body.username, request.body.password)) {
            response.status(400).send("Inputs missing")
        }
        //Next we verify if the user actually exists in the database
        const existingUser = await User.getByUsername(request.body.username);
        //We will include the password comparison logic in this if block
        if (existingUser.status == 201 && (await bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, existingUser.user.Password))) {
            //Create a more lean user object
            const loggedUser = existingUser.user
            delete loggedUser.Password
            const token = jwt.sign({
                    username: request.body.username
                },
                process.env.TOKEN_KEY
            )
            loggedUser.token = token
            return response.status(200).render('adminDashboard.ejs')
        } else {
            response.status(400).send("User not found")
        }
    } catch (err) {
        //No better way of handling this error as of now
        console.log(err)
    }
}

async function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    const authHeader = await req.headers['authorization']
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
    if (token == null) return res.status(200).render('welcome.ejs')
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_KEY, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.status(403).redirect('/login')
        //req.user = user
        next()
    })
}

module.exports = {
    login: login,
    isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
}
```

**routes.js**

```js
var router = require("express").Router()
const auth = require("../controllers/auth.controller.js")
router.post("/login", auth.login)
```

Now, the problem is whenever I click login in the login page and it runs the fetch with the user credentials, nothing happens. I've used console.log to see up to where everything runs and found that everything runs as it should but when response.render is called in **auth.controller.js** nothing happens and the browser stays in the login page.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: shouldn't you be using router.get("/login", auth.login) ?